# In a controller spec, how to find a specific tag in the generated view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I know integration tests are preferred but I need this to be ran in a controller test, I'm testing a gem injecting html code in the view, especially with xhr so this can't be run in a feature spec (if it can, please explain me how :) )

So with rspec controller tests you can assert a selector is present (with capybara) :

```
response.body.should have_selector('#foobar')
```

`has_selector?` will call the `all` method from capybara to find the selector.

What I want to do is get the last child of body and then assert that its id is something in particular.

AFAIK it's not possible to do this with have_selector.

What I would do is :

```
all('body:first-child').first.id.should == '#foobar'
```

However, with Capybara DSL, all is defined like this (more or less):

```
def all(*args)
  page.all(*args)
end
```

And the page will be empty unless I use `visit` but it's for integrations specs.

How can I use capybara `all` method inside an rspec controller test ?

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it right now but after some googling it seems like this would do the trick

```
def page
  Capybara::Node::Simple.new(response.body)
end
```

[Source](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-capybara-on-any-html-fragment-or-page)